# Include YII Application in a script

Tags: yii

I would like to create a PHP script which is called via CLI. And I would like that script to have access to the Yii application. Therefore I created a file called (script.php)

```
// file: script.php
ob_start();
include "index.php"
ob_clean();

echo "This is my script !";
```

I had to include the *ob_start* and *ob_clean* as if I didn't the layout of the application was being render.

Is this the right way to do this? Or should I be doing something else?

Comment: Why are you not using Yii's builtin `CConsoleCommand`? See [here](http://tariffstreet.com/yii/2012/04/implementing-cron-jobs-with-yii-and-cconsolecommand/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, was unaware of it. Taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deal with php console, it is highly recommended to use CConsoleCommand. You can create your file which must act in console in `protected/commands` path. So your class would be something like below:

```
class TestConsoleCommand extends CConsoleCommand{}
```

You can implement your php codes into your functions, but note that the most important method in your class would be `init()` method. Once your consoleCommand runs, this method will be called.

another important note is that, **THE CONFIG OF CONSOLE COMMAND IS DIFFERENT WITH NON-CONSOLE**.  It means that while your ordinary Yii application is running, you are using main.php config file, which is situated in `protected/config/main.php`. In order to access your models and database config ... in your Yii ConsoleApp, You must fulfill the console.php config file which is situated in `protected/config/console.php`.

You can configure your database connection in this file, which you want to access it, while your ConsoleApp is running. You can also import all your classes you need to interact.

Some useful links and documents:

- [CConsoleCommand - represents an executable console command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand)
- [The Definitive Guide to Yii -  Console Applications](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/topics.console)

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Interesting thanks a lot. Reading through it. Not exactly what I was hoping for, but this should do.

Comment: Q: When I run "yiic <command>" how does YII know which appliations command set it should look at ?

Comment: You must pass your php console appplication to Yiic (I mean your file name)

Comment: Thanks. Little confused here. So the entire command would look like ?

Comment: Ah. Figured it. Noticed there is a "yiic" executable for each application.